Livestream not reaching AWS endpoint
I'm trying to stream my live video into Amazon IVS and I don't see it on the live channels.
Is it possible I have a mistake in my FFMPEG configuration?
I'm expecting to see this in my playback url or on the console screen for playback but I see nothing at the moment.
As I understand it, shouldn't I see some kind of playback in the live channels if a stream is being sent that channel?
  async ivsStreamingService(payload: any): Promise<void> {
    const injestServer = '***.global-contribute.live-video.net:443/app/';
    const streamKey = 'sk_us-east-1_*****';
    const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
      '-re',
      '-i', '-',
      '-r', '30',
      '-c:v', 'libx264',
      '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
      '-profile:v', 'main',
      '-preset', 'veryfast',
      '-x264opts', 'nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut',
      '-minrate', '3000k',
      '-maxrate', '3000k',
      '-g', '60',
      '-c:a', 'aac',
      '-b:a', '160k',
      '-ac', '2',
      '-ar', '44100',
      '-f', 'flv',
      `rtmps://${ingestServer}${streamKey}`
    ]);
  
    ffmpeg.stdin.write(payload, (err) => {
      console.log(payload)
      if (err) console.error('Error writing payload to FFmpeg stdin:', err);
    });
  
    ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
  
    ffmpeg.stdin.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error writing to FFmpeg stdin:', err);
    });
  
    ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
    });
  }

Example of the consoled data
I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't receive the stream, as it would appear everything is correct.
